# A regex problem I can't figure out (negative lookbehind)

Tags: c#, regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

how do i do this with regex?

i want to match this string: `-myString`

but i don't want to match the `-myString` in this string: `--myString`

myString is of course anything.

is it even possible?

EDIT:

here's a little more info with what i got so far since i've posted a question:

```
string to match:
some random stuff here -string1, --string2, other stuff here
regex:
(-)([\w])*
```

This regex returns me 3 matches:
`-string1`, `-` and `-string2`

ideally i'd like it to return me only the `-string1` match

Comment: BTW- this is good fun, and the answers are instructive, but regexs may not be the right tool for option processing (which I suspect is what you're trying to do)

Comment: well if i can't do this with regex i'll do it differently. that's why i wanted to know if its possible :)

Comment: I'm sure you _can_ do it. Just not that it is the best way. However, if you know this method, and don't know (say) FSM lexxing, and it doesn't present unacceptable performance or maintenance issues, feel free to ignore me. Cheers.

Comment: since you can't use anchors to the beginning/end of the string, how do you know when string1, string2, etc end?  Whitespace? comma?

Comment: yeah whitespace, comma and other punctuation marks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming your regex engine supports (negative) lookbehind:

```
/(?<!-)-myString/
```

Perl does, Javascript doesn't, for example.

Comment: my regex machine is the one in .Net. No clue if it supports that.

Comment: It does. "(?<!-)-\w+" would be the generic form, assuming that word characters (letters, numbers, underscore) is all that can legally follow the dash in your scenario.

Comment: Tomalak, yep that's exactly what i needed. how about you put that as an answer so i can mark it accepted?

Comment: @Mladen Prajdic: No, that would be a bit unfair. Bart's solution is correct, posting a trivial improvement to get an "accepted" check is stealing. ;-) @Bart, would you add the improved version to your answer?

Comment: Are the / / needed (or even valid) in .Net?

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[^-]*-myString/
```

Testing:

```
[~]$ echo -myString | egrep -e '^[^-]*-myString'
-myString
[~]$ echo --myString | egrep -e '^[^-]*-myString'
[~]$ echo test--myString | egrep -e '^[^-]*-myString'
[~]$ echo test --myString | egrep -e '^[^-]*-myString'
[~]$ echo test -myString | egrep -e '^[^-]*-myString'
test -myString
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to match a string that starts with a single dash, but not one that has multiple dashes?

```
^-[^-]
```

Explanation:

```
^ Matches start of string
- Matches a dash
[^-] Matches anything but a dash
```

Comment: This would allow more dashes later in the string, is that okay?

Comment: dashes are allowed only at the begining of a word. so if there's a space further on there can be dases after it. but then the same rule should apply to them

Comment: This would also only match a dash and one other character. ie it would match -m out of -myString.

Comment: The idea is to pluck matches out of a larger string, so the regex can't be anchored and it has to match the whole word, not just the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

> [^-]{0,1}-[^\w-]+

Comment: According to OP's edit, a sub string match is required, so anchors won't work.

Comment: Updated for the edit.  The only question is how he decides how to end the "mystring" portion.  This example uses whitespace.

Comment: I'm afraid now it is completely broken. ;-) I racked my brain for a simple no-look-behind-required solution as well, but I don't think there is one, when matching on a complete string is required.

Answer (score 0):

based on the last edit, I guess the following expression would work better

```
\b\-\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any look-behinds, use:

```
(?:^|(?:[\s,]))(?:\-)([^-][a-zA-Z_0-9]+)
```

Broken out:

```
(
  ?:^|(?:[\s,])        # Determine if this is at the beginning of the input,
                       # or is preceded by whitespace or a comma
)
(
  ?:\-                 # Check for the first dash
)
(
  [^-][a-zA-Z_0-9]+    # Capture a string that doesn't start with a dash
                       # (the string you are looking for)
)
```